# The variable in the angular .ts is not updated after the click event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good, I have a service that I call from my .ts component which I go through an array with court names, and when I click on an event that I command to call every time I click on a next or back arrow, a counter is added that starts at 0 which index 0 is field 1 and so on.

What happens is that I have a condition that shows me the hours of each day of the week in a calendar and that the view is updated according to the name of the field, this condition equals the array and the counter, my problem is that always stays at index 0 it is not updated, instead in my html if the name of the field changes.

I tried to do it only in the html all the conditions that I have, but there are so many that the code was distorted since I had many ng-containers.

HTML code and where I call the click event:

```
      <div class="col-1 text-end" id="prev">
        <span>&#9664;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2" id="nomCancha">
        <p>{{ canchas[contador] }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 text-start" id="next">
        <span (click)="nextd()">&#9654;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Code of the condition and the variable that is not updated:
if(cancha.name === this.canchas[this.contador])

this.cancha is the array of the cancha and this.contador is the variable that contains the counter that goes through the indices this part in 0

event code:

```
  nextd () {
    this.contador += 1
    if (this.contador === this.canchas.length) {
      this.contador = 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the value of contador property on click, that's fine. But this value is never getting rendered in the UI.
Take a look at [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding).

You also need to let the renderer know that the property value is updated, for that you need event binding, check it [here](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding)

Read the angular doc of [two way binding](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding). It's a combination of both property and event binding. There are other possible solutions that you can do but this should solve your issue.